# jQuery DOM - добавление, удаление узлов

Tags: jquery, javascript, dom

Никак вот не получается реализовать такую задачу: по нажатию на `$("div.block")` должен появляться новый элемент `<div></div>` сразу за ним; по второму нажатию этот же элемент удаляется.

**До**

```
...
<header></header>
<div id="content">
    <div class="logoblock"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
...
```

**После**

```
...
<header></header>
<div id="content">
    <div class="logoblock"></div>
    <div class="block"></div> // кликаем
    <div></div>               // добавляем
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
...
```

Понимаю, конечно, что здесь работает `toggle(click1,click2);`, но не могу понять как добавлять элемент; точнее не могу понять как добраться до элемента, от которого его можно добавить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все делается просто. Есть такая функция [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) для вставки элемента после указанного, и функция [`.insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) для вставки до указанного элемента.

```
$(function () {
    $('div.block').click(function () {
         $('<div>').text('my text').insertAfter(this);
    });
});
```

Comment: Вы снова помогаете! Я, по своей глупости использовал функции `.after()` и `.before()` вместо вами указанных. Сейчас всё работает. Спасибо!

Comment: Вы были на правильном пути, но по всей видимости запутались в параметрах. Вот как тоже самое можно сделать при помощи `after()`:


$(this).after($('<div>').text('my text'));

Answer (score 0):

я вижу решение таким (цвета заданы для наглядности):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Добавление элемента</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#razhdel').click(function(){
            $(this).append('<div id="new">New</div').css('border', '1px solid blue');
            $('#new').css('background', 'blue');
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#razhdel {
    background: red;
    width: 300px;`
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="razhdel">
      bla-bla
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: К сожалению, не то. Для начала я спрашивал, как сделать, чтобы по клику на блок добавлялся новый, не в него (что важно!), а рядом с ним.